# Instantiating DynamoDBQueryExpression with generic classtypes

Tags: java, class, generics, amazon-dynamodb

**Edit:** I was trying to simplify my problem at hand a little, but turns out, it created more confusion instead. Here's the real deal:

I am working with AWS's Java SDK for DynamoDB. Using the DynamoDBMapper class, I am trying to query DynamoDB to retrieve items from a particular table. I have several objects that map to my DynamoDB tables, and I was hoping to have a generic method that could accept the mapped objects, query the table, and return the item result.

Psudo-code:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="testTable")
public class DBObject {

    private String hashKey;
    private String attribute1;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="hashKey")
    public String getHashKey() { return this.hashKey; }
    public void setHashKey(String hashKey)

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="attribute1")
    public String getAttribute1() { return this.attribute1; }
    public void setAttribute1(String attribute1) { this.attribute1 = attribute1; }
}

public class DatabaseRetrieval {

    public DatabaseRetrieval()
    {
        DBObject dbObject = new DBObject();
        dbObject.setHashKey = "12345";

        DBRetrievalAgent agent = new DBRetrievalAgent;
        dbObject = agent.retrieveDBObject(dbObject.getClass(), dbObject);
    }
}

public class DBRetrievalAgent {

    public Object retrieveDBObject(Class<?> classType, Object dbObject)
    {
        DynamoDBQueryExpression<classType> temp = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<classType>().withHashKeyValues(dbObject);

        return this.dynamoDBMapper.query(classType, temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you intend to do with that list and with that Class. How would you populate it, given only a Class? What information does the class provide? You could just use `new ArrayList<Object>`.

Comment: Don't explain it in comments. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use a type witness within your method:

```
public <T> String getResult(Class<T> type) {
    List<T> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    //other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the type as `T` for your **`getResult()` to make it generic** (i.e., accepts any class) as shown below:

```
public <T> String getResult(T t) {
        String result = "";
        List<T> newList = new ArrayList<>();

        // perform actions

        return result; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ArrayList<T> newList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Can you explain why they should "Try this"?